# Graph labeling in which two cycles share at most one vertex

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

Good morning. My friend gave me an interesting graph problem which goes as below.

Given a simple graph in which two cycles share at most one vertex, how to label edges with non negative real number such that for each vertex, sum of the labels of the edges incident on it is not more than a given constant(lets say K) and sum of labels on all edges of the graph is maximum. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Might as well assume that K=1 by scaling the solution. Then you want a fractional matching, which is easily obtainable by linear programming, but presumably you want a solution that exploits the graph structure?

Comment: Yes I can assume K=1 and then scale the solution. but how to find the solution for K=1. Could you please give me more insight into fractional matching algorithm. Any references would be of great help.Thanks

Comment: It's just solving a linear program.

Answer (score 2):

Ugh, this is using a sledgehammer to kill a fly, but here goes.

The class of input graphs is the class of graphs that forbid this minor:

```
  *
 /|\
* | *
 \|/
  *
```

Since the forbidden minor is planar, the class has bounded treewidth, and we can extract a suitable tree decomposition in linear time. The general fractional matching polytope is half-integral, so there exists an optimal solution with edge labels in {0, 1/2, 1}. We can use dynamic programming on the tree decomposition to find an optimal solution in linear time.